# Can we use ASP.NET Web Server controls in ASP.NET MVC using the Spark View Engine?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, spark-view-engine

I am trying to develop an application using ASP.NET MVC 2 with Spark as View Engine for the [Imagine Cup](http://imaginecup.com). To win the IE8 award, I must use some features of IE8. I saw that there are some server controls (Web Slice Control, Accelerator Control, Visual Search Control, Browser Helper Control at http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/WebAppToolkitIE8) that help me use the features of IE8. Can I render them using the Spark View Engine?

Comment: Did you advance in the IE8 category?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why even use server controls?  The IE specific functions are simply XML, JavaScript, and/or HTML.  You'd probably learn more and have better control over the results by doing it without the controls.  I can almost guarantee that Digg, Google, New York Times, and others are not using controls ... and they already have built some ie8-specific features.

Here is some info on each of the ie8 features:

[Accelerators in 15 minutes](http://weblogs.asp.net/draganpanjkov/archive/2009/03/20/writing-ie8-accelerator-in-15-minutes-bookmark-on-delicious.aspx)

[MSDN info on Slices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc304073%28VS.85%29.aspx)

[MSDN info on Search Providers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc848862%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can render user controls to a string and then write them to the page. I have a [post](http://www.abadjimarinov.net/blog/2009/10/29/HowToRenderAspdotNETControlToString.xhtml) how to achieve this. It should work with all view engines since you just have to write a string to the page. There is one restriction - controls that require post back will not work as in asp.net web forms.